# Why I can do this and not the other?

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

Say I want the back button to remain `@"Back"` rather than the title of `UIViewController`

This would work

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

A more sensible option would be this

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
```

Yet this doesn't.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value for self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem is `nil` (and calling any function on `nil object` doesn't do anything).

You have to initialize it with object first.

Answer (score 2):

Initially `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is equivalent to `UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = nil` so just calling `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";` means you are setting the title of `UIBarButtonItem` that doesn't exist. You never actually assign an object to `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`. Also `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is equivalent to `[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem)];` so passing `@"Back"` into this will not work, doing it this way would actually produce a warning I believe. You shouldn't be able to pass a `NSString *` into a parameter that should take `UIBarButtonItem *`.

Whereas `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];` is basically equivalent to `UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];`

To be honest I would say that doing it like

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backBarButtonItem];
```

This would be a lot better and easier to understand but this is just my opinion. Just remember to initialize the object first.